# Is there a free product configurator/ designer extension for Magento?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, extensions

I'am recently building a eShop with the help of Magento and my fellow students for a university seminar. Since the business idea we had to think of resolves around customizable furniture I wanted to know whether or not there are any free or demo versions of these extensions for Magento to be found.

Alternatively we would have to explain the way we would've implemented and configured the plugin but I'd prefer to show them the real thing, integrated into our shop system.

The main feature I would be looking for is the overlay of images according to the given feature options to show the new product, anything else would be a bonus.

Comment: "The main feature I would be looking for is the overlay of images according to the given feature options to show the new product" I don't really understand what you want to have here.
There are already configurable products in Magento, which allows you to create a product which has different criteria (be it size, length, color...)

Comment: Say for instance there is a ver creative and innovative basic product called "blue shoe" and a feature option "red laces" I would like to add an extensions which would use the already detailed shoe product image and another feature option overlay I created which only contains the red laces, it would then be displayed on top of the basic product image and the end result looks like a blue show with red laces.

Comment: Sounds quite advanced to be honest. What you could do is have the configurable product have the blue shoe image. Then all of its simple products have a colored lace png image. On product load, fetch the image of all its sub-products and load them in the DOM. Then on option switching, have the sub-product images appearing on top of the blue shoe picture.